# How to add another target with different bundle ID in the new Xcode5

Tags: xcode, xcode5

In **Xcode 4**, I could easily add another target with different *BundleID*, the purpose is for customisation and testing, I can easily create one by Adding a target.

But now when I add a target, the new file window pops up. How do I do this now?

Comment: And the *New File* window didn't pop-up in Xcode 4?  If not, how did you configure the target?

Comment: Before when I add a target, the existing gets copied, all I need to change is the bundleID, now it gives an empty one and asks for a delegate

Comment: That doesn't make sense; why would adding a target copy an existing target.  I've never seen that behaviour.

Comment: I don't get what you want, but have you tried right clicking the a target then "Duplicate"-ing it? Since it seems like what you only want is to use another info.plist

Comment: Yes, that did the work!

Comment: The guy below already made that statement, accept his answer by clicking the check icon

Comment: Just another build configuration, scheme and info.plist instead of creating a full blown additional target?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a new target with XCode 5 and change the bundle identifier like this :

[image]

Next, in the folder `Supporting Files` in your info-plist :

[image]

Modify the key `Bundle identifier` with the new bundle of your new target :

[image]

Comment: What should I choose in the file pop up?

Comment: Before when I add a target, the existing gets copied, all I need to change is the bundleID, now it gives an empty one and asks for a delegate

Comment: please add a picture on your question, I don't understand

Comment: I already upgraded to Xcode 5.0, I can't show pictures from how I do it in Xcode 4. First, There is already a target, complete with Identity, Launch Image, Deployment Info and App Icons, in Xcode 4, creating a new target copies the settings of the existing target, so it should also have complete settings, but in Xcode 5, it's blank, and it's asking for an AppDelegate

Comment: But, if you create a new Target you don't copy the old one. To do that , right click on your current target and choose `duplicate`